# The type not mapped entity framework 5.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I was following [a video on EF code first](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542).

I tried to follow the exact steps in VS 2012 console app, Please see my code below,

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var context = new EftDbContext())
        {
            context.Blogs.Add(new Blog { Name = "ASP.NET" });
            context.SaveChanges();

            var blogs = from n in context.Blogs
                        orderby n.Name
                        select n;

            foreach (var b in blogs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(b);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
    }

    public class EftDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public EftDbContext()
            : base("name=EftDbContext")
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

However when I run my application it give me following error:

> The type 'EntityFrameworkTest.Program+Post' was not mapped. Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive, nested or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject.

[image]

If someone interested here is my current connection string (I tried multiple option):

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EftDbContext"
     connectionString="Database=TestDB;Server=(local);Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Where do I need to specify the mapping and more importantly why? EF should pick that up no?

I have created another project using VS 2012 web API template and that did not show up this error...

---

Update:

DB does not exist. I am yet to execute this application successfully for the first time on my machine so that EF code first generate the database for me. It is failing in the EftDbContext constructor itself.

---

Update 2: This problem is solved. The issue was all my POCO classes and DbContext was nested in Program class. EF does not like it somehow...

Comment: Should `: base("name=EftDbContext")` not be `: base("EftDbContext")`?

Comment: @MattSull87 I am pretty should you need to keep `name=` in there.

Comment: Does the database already exist?  With Code first, it will create the database the first time, but I think you need to use code migration in order to update the model, or just delete the database and have EF create it for you again.

Comment: @Justin, From what I can see - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj592674 - either can be used.

Comment: Seems like `Post` is a nested type. EF5 does not support nested types. There are some improvements in this area in EF6 AFAIR

Comment: @MattSull87 - Neither works...

Comment: @Justin - No, DB does not exist. I am yet to execute this application successfully so that EF code first generate the database for me. It is failing in the DbContext constructor itself.

Comment: @Pawel - Kindly explain nested type in this context. I am under impression that Post defines navigational properties to Blog. I can see the same code example works in the video I am referring. I suspect something related to machine or framework version.

Comment: @user1529150 - nested class means, a class defined within another class.  Your Blog and Post classes, as well as your dbcontext are all declared within your Program class.  They should not be.

Comment: @MystereMan - Bang on Pawel was right. I moved the classes out of Program class and all worked as expected. I knew its something silly of me... Thanks Pawel for pointing it and MystereMan for making it crystal clear :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From comments above:

Your Blog and Post classes, as well as your dbcontext are all declared within your Program class. They should not be.

EF5 does not support nested types.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Please read the comments where the person who asked the question confirmed that this was the problem they were hitting. It was a comment to my previous comment that pointed out that they were using nested types which are not supported in EF 5

Comment: In that case you could have just comment. Also the answer you provided should have some DOCS, links to support it.

Comment: @Luv - This is not Wikipedia. If docs are necessary, then by all means.  This is an answer, and it provides all that is necessary.  The fact that it's short and succinct is irrelevant.  It could maybe be expanded to say "Move the types out of the Program class", but that doesn't add much.